# Is it possible in Go to use ldflags to set an unassigned integer?

Tags: go

I know there are several ways of accomplishing this with just a little extra code, but it got me curious... Is there a way to set an unassigned integer in a Go application using ldflags? For instance, could you call...

```
go build -ldflags "-X main.CurrentEnvironment 1"
```

And have it set:

```
package main

var CurrentEnvironment int

func main() {

    ...

}
```

I couldn't find any documentation supporting this so I presume the answer is no but maybe there's a way.

Comment: No. The docs specifically say -X is to set a string.

Comment: Do you have a reference to that? I couldn't find it for the life of me. Otherwise, thanks.

Comment: @JimB: The answer section is here: ↓↓↓↓↓↓

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the -X flag to set a string value only ([docs](http://golang.org/cmd/link/)). You could then convert it to an int in your main function with [Atoi](http://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#Atoi).